# Spring Cloud Feign Client duplicate list values

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-feign

I have this interface mapping my rest client using Spring cloud Feign.

```
@FeignClient(url = "http://localhost:8080")
public interface RestClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "?ids={ids}", method = GET)
    List<Posicao> get(@RequestParam(value = "ids") List ids);
}
```

I have a list in my parameters, calling the client I have this request:

```
restClient.get(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
```

http://localhost:8080/ids=1,2,1,2

It's duplicating the list values!

I already tried using an array, an integer and string generic list, but no success.

Comment: I've duplicated the issue and created an issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/496

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `?ids={ids}` from `@RequestMapping` fixes the problem.  Only **path** parameters need to go there.