# Spring Cloud Feign Client @RequestParam with List parameter creates a wrong request

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a Spring Clound Feign Client mapping defined as following

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/search/findByIdIn")
Resources<MyClass> get(@RequestParam("ids") List<Long> ids);
```

when I call

```
feignClient.get(Arrays.asList(1L,2L,3L))
```

according to what I can see in the debugger, the feign-core library forms the following request:

```
/search/findByIdIn?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3
```

instead of expected

```
/search/findByIdIn?ids=1,2,3
```

which would be correct for the server Spring Data REST endpoint declared in the same way as my Feign client method.

Thus, because of this issue, the request always returns empty set.

I have seen similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098906/spring-cloud-feign-client-duplicate-list-values), but it looks like the Feign client was working as I expect back in 2015.

I am using:

- spring-cloud-starter-feign version 1.2.4.RELEASE
- feign-httpclient version 9.4.0
- feign-core version 9.4.0

Is there a way to correct the behaviour and "marry" the Spring Cloud Feign Client with the Spring Data REST defined endpoints?

Comment: This may have an impact https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1526. You might try Dalston.SNAPSHOT, which brings in spring-cloud-netflix 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. If not you should open an issue.

Comment: @spencergibb That seems to the behaviour indeed:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1634

Comment: Please also see an example project:
https://github.com/abinet/demo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue with multiple occurence of the parametre instead of the expected comma separated sequence of items. The solution was really simple:

In my feign client I used arrays

`feignClient.get(new Long[]{1L,2L,3L})`

instead of collection/list:

`feignClient.get(Arrays.asList(1L,2L,3L))`

Answer (score 6):

In Feign you can annotate your controller with the following

`@CollectionFormat(feign.CollectionFormat.CSV)` and it will process collections in

the CSV format findByIdIn?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3

Answer (score 5):

Thanks **@prola** for your answer.

Just to add an explicit example, `@CollectionFormat(feign.CollectionFormat.CSV)` annotation targets a method; you can't apply globally to your Feign Client interface.

So each method will be similar to:

```kotlin
@RequestMapping(value = ["/objects"], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
@CollectionFormat(feign.CollectionFormat.CSV)
fun findById(
    @RequestParam(value = "object.id", required = true) id: String,
    @RequestParam(value = "object.fields", required = false) objectFields: List<String> = DEFAULT_FIELDS_LIST,
    @RequestParam(value = "format") format: String = FORMAT,
): ResponseEntity<ObjectsDTO>
```

The result will be

```
/objects?object.fields=size,weight,location
```

instead of

```
/objects?object.fields=size&object.fields=weight&object.fields=location
```

You can also refer to:

- [1.16.Feign CollectionFormat support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#feign-collectionformat-support)
- [OpenFeign #542: Support Multiple Collection Formats](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/542)

Comment: This @CollectionFormat(feign.CollectionFormat.CSV) saved my 2 days, thanks a lot

Comment: Another option is to declare the CSV format  is, for example : 
  @RequestLine(
      value = "GET "/books?categories={categories}", collectionFormat = CollectionFormat.CSV)

Answer (score 2):

I've just battled with this today, and the solution for me was surprisingly simple.

If you use brackets `[]` for denoting query array:

```java
Resources<MyClass> get(@RequestParam("ids[]") List<Long> ids);
```

it will create a request that looks like this

```
/search/findByIdIn?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3
```

Most server side frameworks will interpret this as an array.
If your server is also in spring then you can pick this up like this

```java
@GetMapping("/search/findByIdIn")
public ResponseEntity findByIdIn(@RequestParam("ids[]") List<Long> ids) { ... }
```

Just keep in mind that the query has to be encoded, `[]` gets encoded to `%5B%5D`.