# Send multiple key in Feign Client

Tags: java, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I have a nxt request POST with form url encoded using Feign Client

```
@FeignClient(
        url = "${url}", configuration = NxtApi.Configuration.class)
public interface NxtApi {

    @PostMapping(value = "nxt", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    String new(
            @RequestParam String requestType, @RequestBody Map<String, ?> payload);

    class Configuration {

        @Bean
        Encoder feignFormEncoder(ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> converters) {
            return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(converters));
        }

        @Bean
        Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
            return Logger.Level.FULL;
        }

    }
}
```

I want to send the same key with two values

```
  Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
  param.put("filter", valueOne);
  param.put("filter", valueTwo);
  api.new("asset",param);
```

**I need something like that**

```
filter=valueOne&filter=valueTwo
```

But it's being sent like this (Request response in the log)

```
filter=[valueOne,valueTwo]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use a List of String values instead of a Map.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "nxt", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
String new(@RequestParam String requestType, @RequestParam("filter") List<String> filter, @RequestBody Map<String, ?> payload);
```

as I found it here: [Spring Cloud Feign Client @RequestParam with List parameter creates a wrong request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744542/spring-cloud-feign-client-requestparam-with-list-parameter-creates-a-wrong-requ)